# Return a DTO instead of a User entity

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony with Twig. In Twig I have access to the app.user variable. This variable returns the custom user entity of the logged in user.

While this is great, I'd like to return a parsed DTO of the user entity. This because of the amount of relationships the user entity has with other entities. True, I need this data on every page of a logged in user, but it also turns the user entity into a large object.

Is there a way to return a parsed DTO when calling app.user in Twig?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Doctrine relations should be Lazy loaded (=only loaded if you use these properties).

See here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-object-graph-traversal

So you can't optimize this with avoiding relations to be hydrated, since it is already the default behaviour.

To hydrate the relations you can configure them with fetch="EAGER"

Comment: I know that if you don't use these properties on every page, they should be lazy loaded. However, in this project, these properties should always be loaded because they're always used. My question was if I could make `app.user` return a DTO instead of an entity.

Comment: OK, no you can't but you can write your own Twig Extension to prowide your DTO and crete it yourself.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you can also edit your user relation to set them with fetch="EAGER"